# Why do we have a 'set-theory' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's an intriguing (if baffling) question on the main site: [Inversions of Pitch Class set prime numbers](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/40916/2125) and it has the tag [set-theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-theory).

Why do we have a set-theory tag? What does it have to do with music practice and theory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have a set theory tag because we cover [set theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory_(music)) and it's kind of a step outside of typical theory so a separate tag is optimal for covering this subject. The four questions tagged with it are prime examples of questions the tag should be used on and I'm pretty sure there are a few more questions that should have that tag.